# Role of friction in circular motion

Tags: friction

If a body is moving in a circular path, then, why do we take *The direction of friction towards the centre of circular path* and why ***It is static friction***

Comment: You don't—in the general case—get to assume that friction is centripetal. But textbooks and teachers often set up situations in which friction is the thing making the motion circular.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, it seems like you are asking about an object undergoing uniform circular motion with friction being the only force acting on the object.

In order for uniform circular motion to occur, there must be a force that acts towards the center of the circle. This is so that only the direction of the velocity vector changes. If there were force components in other directions, the object would either be speeding up or slowing down.

As for why it is static friction, this is the case whenever there is no relative motion (sliding) between the two surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably talking about a car making a turn, right? Be more specific in the future, thanks in advance.

In a rotating motion there has to be a force that attributes for the centripetal force. For a car making a turn that is friction of the tires. It is a static friction because the tires don’t turn in that direction (assuming the car doesn’t slip, then it would be kinetic friction). There is however also a ‘rolling component’ to the friction that points in the opposite direction of the motion.